# Possible to use/transpile es6 syntax *inside* Angular 1.x templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, something like this will break

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{`${name}`}}!
</div>
```

With the error

```
Error: Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [`] in expression [`${name}`].
```

Would it be possible to transpile the JS in Angular 1.x templates?

Comment: Probably but feels kinda redundant doesn't it?

Comment: Apologies for the contrived example. The actual usage scenario is more like `ng-click="$ctrl.doAThing({key: \`${foo}->${bar}: ${bat}!\`, ... })"`